# QtWebEngineWidgets открытие сайта на новой вкладке при нажатии Ctrl+ЛКМ или СКМ по ссылке

Tags: python, pyqt6, pyside6, qwebengineview, qtwebengine

При нажатии на ссылку при помощи `Ctrl+ЛКМ` или `СКМ` сайт должен открываться в новой вкладке

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Web')
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        web_view = QWebEngineView()
        web_view.setUrl('https://google.com')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view, 'tab title')

    def add_tab(self, url):
        web_view = QWebEngineView()
        web_view.setUrl(url)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view, 'tab title')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    availableGeometry = mainWin.screen().availableGeometry()
    mainWin.resize(availableGeometry.width() * 2 / 3, availableGeometry.height() * 2 / 3)
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Догадался, что нужно использовать [**WebBrowserBackgroundTab**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#WebWindowType-enum)

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWebEngineCore import QWebEnginePage
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QTabWidget)


class MyWebView(QWebEngineView):
    def createWindow(self, type_):
        if type_ == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserBackgroundTab:
            # Вызывается при Ctrl+ЛКМ / СКМ
            return self.window().add_tab(self.url())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Web')
        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        web_view = MyWebView()
        web_view.setUrl('https://google.com')
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view, 'tab title')

    def add_tab(self, url):
        web_view = MyWebView()
        web_view.setUrl(url)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(web_view, 'tab title')
        return web_view  # Возвращаем QWebEngineView для запроса


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    availableGeometry = mainWin.screen().availableGeometry()
    mainWin.resize(availableGeometry.width() * 2 / 3, availableGeometry.height() * 2 / 3)
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```